# Download Static Files by name Django

Tags: python, django, download

I am creating a site with `Django` where users upload a file (for example `test.png`) which is then processed and a new file (`test.csv`) is created in the local directory `../django/myproject/mysite/csv/test.csv`.
Users can keep uploading files and more `.csv` files are created. A result page will show the `.csv` files and the user can download those files.

However, I'm confused as I can't download them.

**views.py**

```
def make_csv(request):
    ...
    csv_filename = str(in_csv_file)

    #send to result page
    return render(request, 'thesite/results.html', {"csv_filename": csv_filename})

def download_csv(request, csvfile):
    path = os.path.join(SETTING_DIR)
    filename = path + csvfile + ".csv"
    filewrapper = FileWrapper(open(filename, 'rb'))
    response = HttpResponse(filewrapper, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(csvfile +".csv")

    return response
```

**results.html**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{csv_filename}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href='/thesite/download_csv/{{csv_filename}}'>
                Download                  {# do i add something here?  #}
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path(
        'download_csv/(?P<csvfile>.+)$/',
        views.download_csv,
        name='download_csv'),             # or do I add something here??
]
```

I'm sorry if my question is unclear. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just put a link to the cvs file in your html.  when someone clicks on it, the file will be get downloaded … maybe they might have to right click and choose 'Save As ...'. Downloading is more a function of the browser instead of your Django server.  You don't need to put anything for downloading in your urlpatterns.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but is it like this? Because I would get a page not found error as it links to http://127.0.0.1:8000/django/myproject/mysite/csvtest.csv    
  <td>{{ file }}</td>
<td><a href="/django/myproject/mysite/csv{{ file }}">Download</a></td>

Comment: You need to present a valid link to your cvs file in your html.  If it is not /Django/myproject… then it is something else.  Adding crap to your urlpatterns won't change that fact.  What is your STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in your settings file?

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, managed to find the problem. Thank you

Comment: You should post an the answer of delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the static URL. Also make sure your STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL are set correctly.

```
{% load static %}     #first load static files at the top of template

<a href="{% static '/path/to/{{csv_filename}}' %}">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it from STATIC_URL